# Apply value to group

Tags: sql, sql-server

need help with,
if any ID with same Groupid has Yes in Payable, add Yes value to Results, otherwise blank.
This should be applicable for hundreds of IDs grouped in hundreds of GroupIDs.

| ID | GroupID | Payable | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | a | Yes | Yes |
| 222 | a |  | Yes |
| 333 | a |  | Yes |
| 444 | b |  | Yes |
| 555 | b | Yes | Yes |
| 777 | b |  | Yes |
| 888 | c |  |  |

I tried to group based on groupID and created a case where groupId count equals or is higher as 1 and the eligibility is Yes.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a tag to indicate the database you're working with, as syntax can vary a little between different databases.

Comment: MS SQL , sorry i am newbie

Comment: Corrected my statement. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear due to lack of information about constraints, all the values in table etc.
With the given information tho, your task might be done by following query:

```
with groupData as
(
   Select groupid,payable from put_your_table_name_here
   where payable is not null
   group by groupid
)
Select pt.id
      ,pt.groupId
      ,gd.payable
      ,pt.result
from put_your_table_name_here pt
left join groupData gd on gd.groupid=pt.groupid
```

The query has it drawbacks- you should give some more info about constraints, but generally it should work.
If you wouldnt want to have null values in payable column, you could change left join to join.

Comment: updated my request.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(ID,    GroupID,    Payable)AS
(
  SELECT 111,'A','YES'
     UNION ALL
  SELECT 222,'A',''
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 333,'A',''
     UNION ALL
  SELECT 444,'B',''
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 555,'B','YES'
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 777,'B',''
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 888,'C',''


)
SELECT C.ID,C.GroupID,C.Payable,F.FLAG
FROM CTE AS C
JOIN
(
   SELECT X.GROUPID,MAX(PAYABLE)FLAG
     FROM CTE AS X
      GROUP BY X.GroupID
)F ON C.GroupID=F.GroupID
 ORDER BY C.ID;
```

You can try something like this
or

```
SELECT C.ID,C.GroupID,C.Payable,
 FIRST_VALUE(C.PAYABLE)OVER(PARTITION BY C.GROUPID ORDER BY C.PAYABLE    DESC)XCOL
FROM CTE AS C
ORDER BY C.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data (ID,GroupID,Payable) as (
Select 111, 'a',    'Yes' from dual union all
Select 222, 'a',    null from dual union all
Select 333, 'a',    null from dual union all
Select 444, 'b',    null from dual union all
Select 555, 'b',    'Yes' from dual union all
Select 777, 'b',    null from dual union all
Select 888, 'c',    null from dual
)
,result as(
select  GroupID, case when Count(*) > 1 then 'Yes' else null end Result
from data
group by  GroupID)
Select * from data
Join result on data.GroupID = result.GroupID
order by data.ID,data.GroupID
```

[Db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa8c8f6c7be16a2070b5ed393b7c13d9)